# jQuery checkbox validation with alt-checkbox

Tags: jquery, validation, checkbox

I am using jquery 1.9.1 with alt-checkbox (http://alt-checkbox.starikovs.com/) to create a set of 'nice' checkboxes. I also want to ensure that at least one of the checkboxes is selected so I am using the jQuery Validation plugin. Validation works fine without the alt-checkbox styling but when I add the styling the validation fails.

The (stripped down) raw code for the checkboxes is:

```
<form id="form" name ="form">
  <input type="checkbox" name="groups[]" class="checkbox" value="1">
  <input type="checkbox" name="groups[]" class="checkbox" value="2">
</form>
```

The alt-checkbox styling is added through:

```
<script>
  jQuery(".checkbox").altCheckbox({
  });
</script>
```

And the validation is done through:

```
$("#form").validate({

    rules: {              
        'groups[]': {
          required: true,
        }
      },

      messages: {
        'groups[]': "Please select at least one group"    
      }         
});
 });
</script>
```

The alt-checkbox renders:

```
<a href="#" class="alt-checkbox fontawesome-ok medium outline-unchecked"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="groups[]" id="groups[]" class="checkbox" value="1" style="display: none;"/>
<a href="#" class="alt-checkbox fontawesome-ok medium outline-unchecked checked"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="groups[]" id="groups[]" class="checkbox" value="2" style="display: none;"/>
```

I've tried various things to get it working including adding validate="required:true, minlength:2" to the first checkbox without luck. Any suggestions?

Comment: Like you can see altCheckbox hide standard checkboxes and put on this place `anchor` Validate plugin works on inputs element not anchors.

Comment: As @WooCaSh points, you should then use `if( $('.alt-checkbox').filter('.checked').length == 0 ) { return false; }`

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is allow jQuery Validate to execute on hidden elements.  It will still work with your alternative checkbox implementation:

```
$("#form").validate({
    ignore:'',//by default it ignores hidden inputs, so setting this to blank overrides that
    rules: {              
        'groups[]': {
          required: true,
        }
      },

      messages: {
        'groups[]': "Please select at least one group"    
      }         
});
```